# What is the Lie group infinitesimal generator?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, lie-groups

Our prof gave us the definition of the Lie group infinitesimal generator and it's kth-coordinate, he also explained why the kth-coordinate is called "the kth-coordinate", but nonetheless he didn't want to explain the Lie group infinitesimal generator because "we will understand it later as the course will continue".

I'm fine with that explanation but nevertheless I'd really like to at least know why we are defining the Lie group infinitesimal generator in the first place, and where it is used. Maybe nothing too deep as we just started working with Lie groups. But I want to grasp the intuition behind the Lie group infinitesimal generator

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A Lie group is a group that is also a manifold. Formally the generators are a basis for the tangent space of the identity element in the group.

Informally you can think of the generators as corresponding to small group transformations which are "near" the identity. Every element in the connected component of the group can be "generated" by repeatedly applying these transformations.

As an example consider the positive real numbers with multiplications as the group operation. The identity element of this group is the real number $1$. The tangent space at $1$ is just the real line, and the tangent vector $\sigma=+1$ can be taken as a basis for this 1D space.

Now consider the "infinitesimal transformation" which is "in the neighborhood of the identity element" of our group,

$g = 1+\epsilon \sigma,$

where $\epsilon$ is some "small" real number (can be positive or negative).

For a finite epsilon we can approximately represent most members of our group from repeated multiplication of $g$.

For instance suppose $\epsilon=0.001$ and we want to represent the group element $2$.

Then our approximate $g$ would be $1.001$ and we could represent $2$ by $g^{693}=1.999013$. Now of course we don't need to be so approximate. Using calculus we can get an exact representation.

Let $g_\theta$ be a member of the group labelled by a real number $\theta$. Then we can express $g_\theta$ in terms of our generator $g$ by the following limit.

$$g_\theta = \lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} (1+\theta \cdot \sigma /N)^N = e^{\theta \cdot \sigma}$$

Here I have replaced $\epsilon$ with $\theta/N$ and taken the limit as the exponent $N$ approaches infinity.

Now we have a way of representing our entire group in terms of this function $exp(\theta \cdot \sigma)$ where $\theta$ labels the different elements of the group.

The essential idea of Lie groups is to represent the connected component of your group-manifold in terms of the exponential map applied to a linear combination of your generators. The relations between the generators themselves can reveal a lot about the structure of the group.

Comment: Is this the reason why a=0, because we want to generate ODEs around that neutral element as you said? So basically it's a ODE generator which depends on how we define our Transformation T_a?

Comment: I would need more context for your exact application, but if I understand you correctly then yes. The transformations will be defined relative to the "neutral" or "identity" transformation where your continuous parameter equal zero for that element.

Comment: And the Lie group infinitesimal generator will be giving us another ODE, right? Because it's a sum of partial derivatives. If we have this differential equation which is given by the Lie group infinitesimal generator, what can we do with that? Where can we apply this and for what?

Comment: The generator, being an element of the tangent space, can be represented as a differential operator which acts on smooth functions defined over the manifold. These can be used to construct differential equations depending on the context. As an example consider the rotational group SO(3) as it is applied in Quantum Mechanics. Rotations about the z-axis are generated by $L_z = y \partial_x - x \partial_y$ (I may have the overall sign backwards for this expression). The component of angular momentum about the z-axis is represented by the eigenvalues of this operator $L_z \psi = \hbar m \psi$.

Comment: Do you need any further clarification/explanation? If not then it would be appropriate to accept the answer.

Comment: I guess I kind of get it, as I said we just started this topic

Comment: Feel free to ping me in the future if additional questions arrise.